# Render SQL Template file using sqlfluff API

Tags: python, jinja2, sqlfluff

Is there any way to render a sql template file using the `sqlfluff` API.

Currently I can render using the command:

```
sqlfluff render -d <dialect> some_template.sql
```

Is there any way for me to switch from above command to python API?
(In addition, after running the sqlfluff lint command in the ci/cd code, are the sql template files changed (apply jinja template))
Sorry for my English, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The CLI functions can be found here, which includes `render`:
https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/blob/main/src/sqlfluff/cli/commands.py#L1116

The python API currently only seems to contain `.lint()`, `.fix()` and `.parse()` and not `.render()`:
https://github.com/sqlfluff/sqlfluff/blob/main/src/sqlfluff/api/simple.py#L59